# How do I subset multiple dataframes based on a shared column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to read into three omics datasets - methylation, cnv, and mRNA expression.

First, I removed duplicated columns and sort by index for all 3 dataframes `mrna`, `meth`, and `cna` separately. These dataframes are then concatenated to form one dataframe `common`.

Eventually, I want the `common` dataframe to only contain "Hugo_Symbol" column that are the same in all three dataframes `mrna`, `meth`, and `cna`.

```
import re

dfs = [mrna, meth, cna]

common = pd.concat(dfs, join='inner')
```

Here, the `common` dataframe has a `48625 rows × 348 columns` dimension.

Now, I only want to keep the rows in `common` if the row value is the same across all the three original dataframes `mrna`, `cna`, and `meth`.

```
keep_col = common.drop_duplicates(keep="first")["Hugo_Symbol"]
common = common[common.set_index(["Hugo_Symbol"]).index.isin(keep_col)]
```

I'm expecting the newly subsetted `common` dataframe to have # of rows equal to the length of `keep_col`

```
len(keep_col)
48618
```

However, the subsetted `common` dataframe instead has a `48625 rows × 348 columns` dimension, meaning that none of the rows were removed/subsetted.

Example dataframes:

mrna

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA-1 | TCGA-2 | TCGA-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 1 | DEF | 678 | 187 | 456 |
| 2 | MNO | 742 | 147 | 147 |
| 3 | VWX | 184 | 195 | 268 |

cna

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA-1 | TCGA-2 | TCGA-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DEF | 456 | 123 | 321 |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 2 | GHI | 694 | 284 | 270 |
| 3 | JKL | 384 | 843 | 147 |

meth

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA-1 | TCGA-2 | TCGA-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DEF | 456 | 123 | 432 |
| 1 | PQR | 285 | 226 | 732 |
| 2 | STU | 225 | 632 | 532 |
| 3 | ABC | 123 | 456 | 789 |

In this example, the rows with Hugo_Symbol `ABC` and `DEF` are retained because all three dataframes have these Hugo_Symbols. Hence, the `common` dataframe, as (previously) sorted by index, would be:
`common`

|  | Hugo_Symbol | TCGA-1 | TCGA-2 | TCGA-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 1 | DEF | 456 | 123 | 321 |

Answer (score 0):

Given that the entire row must be equal, as by my first answer below returns:

```
import pandas as pd

mrna = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['ABC','DEF','MNO','VWX'],
'TCGA-1': [123, 678, 742, 184,],
'TCGA-2': [456, 187, 147, 195,],
'TCGA-3': [789, 456, 147, 268,],
}

cna = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['DEF','ABC','GHI','JKL',],
'TCGA-1': [456, 123, 694, 384,],
'TCGA-2': [123, 456, 284, 843,],
'TCGA-3': [321, 789, 270, 147,],
}


meth = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['DEF','PQR','STU','ABC',],
'TCGA-1': [456, 285, 225, 123,],
'TCGA-2': [123, 226, 632, 456,],
'TCGA-3': [432, 732, 532, 789,],
}



dfs = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mrna), pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cna), pd.DataFrame.from_dict(meth)]
common = pd.DataFrame(set.intersection(*[set([tuple(l) for l in df.values.tolist()])\
                                         for df in dfs]), columns=dfs[0].columns)
print(f"common: \n{common}")

"""
common:
  Hugo_Symbol  TCGA-1  TCGA-2  TCGA-3
0         ABC     123     456     789
"""
```

Given that only 'Hugo_Symbol' column is relevant, below returns:
import pandas as pd

```
mrna = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['ABC','DEF','MNO','VWX'],
'TCGA-1': [123, 678, 742, 184,],
'TCGA-2': [456, 187, 147, 195,],
'TCGA-3': [789, 456, 147, 268,],
}

cna = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['DEF','ABC','GHI','JKL',],
'TCGA-1': [456, 123, 694, 384,],
'TCGA-2': [123, 456, 284, 843,],
'TCGA-3': [321, 789, 270, 147,],
}


meth = {
'Hugo_Symbol': ['DEF','PQR','STU','ABC',],
'TCGA-1': [456, 285, 225, 123,],
'TCGA-2': [123, 226, 632, 456,],
'TCGA-3': [432, 732, 532, 789,],
}



dfs = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mrna), pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cna), pd.DataFrame.from_dict(meth)]

hugoFilter = set.intersection(*[set(df.loc[:, 'Hugo_Symbol'].values.tolist()) for df in dfs])
common = pd.concat(dfs)
common = common[common.Hugo_Symbol.isin(hugoFilter)].drop_duplicates(keep="first", subset='Hugo_Symbol')
print(f"common: \n{common}")

"""
common:
  Hugo_Symbol  TCGA-1  TCGA-2  TCGA-3
0         ABC     123     456     789
1         DEF     678     187     456
NOTE: make sure the DEF from the corrrect DF is returned, values differ.
"""
```

Comment: Using your code, `common` returns only column names. But I want column to be a dataframe.

Comment: This is because the illustrative dfs I created using random.randint does not always have common values due to its limited size. You have to increase the size parameter to a meaningful value to always see results. Or repeat the run multipe times.

Comment: Try size=(15, 2)

Comment: I used `common = pd.DataFrame(set.intersection(*[set([tuple(l) for l in df.values.tolist()]) for df in dfs]), columns=dfs[0].columns)` in place of `common = pd.concat(dfs, join='inner')` and it returned zero rows. I didn't use your `dfs` code because I'm using `dfs = [mrna, meth, cna]`, which is a list of dataframe.

Comment: please look at the edited question, under "second attempt". Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an df.head(10) for the 3 dfs [mrna, meth, cna]?

Comment: I uploaded example data but its just a small subset of three large dataframes.

Comment: Your second piece of code is what I needed! Except that I use `join="inner"` in `pd.concat`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would the ideal output look like, is this what you're trying to do? I feel like there's some confusion between columns and rows...

```
dfs = [mrna, meth]

def do_stuff(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df).T
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    return df

mrna, meth = map(do_stuff, dfs)

print(pd.concat([mrna, meth], axis=1).dropna())
```

Output:

```
Hugo_Symbol        AACS   FSTL1   ELMO2 CREB3L1   RPS11   PNMA1    MMP2  \
TCGA-02-0001-01 -0.5909 -0.9099 -2.3351  0.2216  0.6798   -2.48  0.7912   
TCGA-02-0003-01 -0.5154  0.0896   -1.17  0.1255  0.2374 -3.2629  1.2846   
TCGA-02-0007-01  0.6932 -5.6511 -2.8365  2.0026 -0.6326 -1.3741  -3.437   

Hugo_Symbol      SAMD4A SMARCD3   A4GNT     MEOX2     COX8C     IMPA2  \
TCGA-02-0001-01 -1.4578 -3.8009  3.4868  0.041451  0.981055   0.01858   
TCGA-02-0003-01  -1.474 -2.9891 -0.1511   0.10389  0.989163  0.127843   
TCGA-02-0007-01  -1.047  -4.185  2.1816  0.025519  0.985666  0.018484   

Hugo_Symbol          TTC8   TMEM186    RETSAT     TULP1     TAF15   CCDC88B  \
TCGA-02-0001-01  0.037853  0.858835  0.028956  0.895705  0.024163   0.64503   
TCGA-02-0003-01  0.061488  0.718749  0.037052  0.875983   0.02025  0.338662   
TCGA-02-0007-01  0.084045  0.862945  0.029969  0.930821   0.02238  0.319357   

Hugo_Symbol       EPB41L3  
TCGA-02-0001-01  0.025546  
TCGA-02-0003-01  0.879701  
TCGA-02-0007-01  0.019343
```

Comment: I want to find rows that are the same in all three dataframes. Then, I want to create a dataframe based on these rows.

Comment: I don't want to transform the dataframe. Rows will still be rows and columns will be columns.